# Функция array.map

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, как перебрать массив `auto` и в зависимости от значения `item` вернуть в `result` определенное значение?

```js
auto = ["bmw", "honda", "fiat"];
result = auto.map((item, index) => {
    ???
});
```

Например:

```
if bmw, то в result пишем "m5"
if honda, то в result пишем "accord"
if fiat, то в result пишем "punto"
```

Comment: Что  не получилось?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ещё как вариант предварительно создать объект, в котором будут записаны нужные ассоциации:

```js
let associations = {
  'bmw': 'm5',
  'honda': 'accord',
  'fiat': 'punto'
};

let auto = ['bmw', 'honda', 'fiat'];
let result = auto.map(item => associations[item]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: о, классный вариант! (+)

Answer (score 3):

```js
var auto = ["bmw", "honda", "fiat"];

var result = auto.map( item => {
  if (item == "bmw") return "m5";
  else if (item == "honda") return "accord";
  else if (item == "fiat") return "punto";
  else return "";
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `index` наверно не нужен)

Comment: @diraria да, я уже думал над этим )) и switch тоже думал написать, но что-то написал именно так. сейчас его уберу, подумал может он нужен автору зачем-то

Comment: тогда ещё и скобки вокруг `item` можно убрать))

Comment: @diraria про это тоже думал )) но проверить сработает или нет было лень, а зря, сейчас проверю

Comment: @diraria сработало

Answer (score 3):

У Вас в коде лишняя скобка после `index)`.

```js
var auto = ["bmw", "honda", "fiat"];

var result = auto.map((item, index, arr) => {
  switch(item) {
    case "bmw":
      return "m5";
    case "honda":
      return "accord";
    case "fiat":
      return "punto";
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: и ещё скобки в конце map не хватает в вопросе ))

Comment: А внутри map можно еще цикл for запускать? Например пройтись там по item?

Comment: @Sinevik можно, конечно. Обычная функция.

Comment: @Sinevik Обратите внимание на третий параметр функции, подаваемой в `map` - это сам массив.